# Derive Monad from Fay newtype in order to enable do notation

Tags: fay

I want to create a different classes of side-effecty functions, so I can mark some of the side-effects as safer than other ones.

I'd like to create a *newtype* over the `Fay` side-effect monad and use it in the *do* notation, so I declare it like this:

```fay
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}
import "base" Control.Monad
newtype ReadFay a = ReadFay { readFay :: Fay a } deriving Monad
```

A this point, the compiler cannot find the `base` package. It is possible to do it in fay somehow?

I can still create my own versions of `>>=`, `return`, etc. for the `ReadFay`, but being able to use it in *do* notation would be nice.

Or, is there a better way, how to create a different classes of side-effect than this my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I need to enable

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
```

to override the functions, that the *do* notation is calling. 
Then I need to implement the wrapping and unwrapping to/from the *newtype* in the functions that I plan to use in the *do* notation and shadow the `Prelude` ones:

```
myFayReturn :: a -> ReadFay a
myFayReturn x = ReadFay $ return x

myFayBind :: ReadFay a -> (a -> ReadFay b) -> ReadFay b
myFayBind = \a b -> ReadFay $ runReadFay a >>= (runReadFay . b)

newtype ReadFay a = ReadFay { runReadFay :: Fay a }

doNotation :: ReadFay ()
doNotation = let
    x >>= y = myFayBind x y
    return = myFayReturn
    in do
        u <- ReadFay $ putStrLn "A"
        return ()
```